# Reputation glitch after undownvote

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

Today I got two downvotes on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Then, the 21<sup>st</sup> upvote of the day got me another 4 points to the repcap, with +245 for the day and 25,956 total. Some time later, one of the downvotes was removed.

Now the reputation in the top bar and on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2012-05-02%2016:06:28Z) shows 25,954, the reputation tab in my profile shows +247 for the day, the dropdown from the topbar +243.

[/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) correctly adjusted the 21<sup>st</sup> upvote to count +2 and reports +245 for the day, 25,956 total as it should, so a recalc will fix it. Nevertheless, perhaps someone wants to look into it.

Comment: Something similar happened to me on Super User on May 1. One of the upvotes just wouldn't stick.