# Reputation glitch after user removal

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

On Math.SE, after a serial upvoting followed by a user removal, there is a discrepancy between what [/reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) reports, and the [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r?tab=reputation) in my profile.

According to the former, I earned 80 reputation points yesterday (24 September 2021), with a total score of 76618 at the end of the day:

```
-- 2021-09-23 rep +110  = 76538     
 2   4256335 (10)
 1   4256335 (15)
 1   4259040 (15)
 2   4259040 (10)
 2   4259040 (10)
 2   4259040 [10]
 2   4259344 [10]
-- 2021-09-24 rep +80   = 76618
```

According to the latter, it is 70 points for the day,  with a total score of 76608 at the end of the day:

[image]

It seems that the vote on https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4259344/42969 from yesterday is counted in in /reputation, but not in the reputation tab of my profile on Math.SE.

There are similar questions about reputation after a user removal ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312603/196432), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165679/196432)), but those seem to be about voting and removal occurring on *different days.* Also these do not explain the reported discrepancy, unless I am mistaken.

Another similar issue was reported here: [Reputation glitch after undownvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131128/196432), but that is about undownvote, not user removal, and it was never answered.

All this happened yesterday, so I would assume that any rep recalculation would have happened in the meantime.

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens any time you have a reputation reversal that affects the current day. For accounting purposes, the votes that were reversed still have to be calculated as gaining reputation, or the reversal makes no sense. This also plays oddly with the reputation cap, because your progress towards the cap is stored in a denormalized field on the User (it is too expensive to calculate your cap every single time you receive a vote).

Because it is denormalized, new upvotes still count as 0 as they come in on that day, when they should give you 10 if the invalidated votes are being ignored. This is only fixed by the recalculation script, which can be triggered for your user in a variety of situations (most commonly, when a post of yours is deleted or undeleted). Once it's run, it recalculates the entire day to count reputation correctly. The /reputation report, on the other hand, calculates everything in real time instead of using the cached reputation history. It is generally what your reputation *should be* if it were recalculated now.